# Traversing all vertices and return to start vertex withDFS

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a DFS Graph Traversal in Python where I have to start at vertex 1 and visit all the vertices and end my search at the starting vertex i.e at Vertex 1. The Graph with vertex edge list is:

```
{1: [2, 5, 6, 7],
 2: [1, 3, 4, 8],
 3: [2, 8],
 4: [2, 7],
 5: [1, 6, 8],
 6: [1, 5, 8],
 7: [1, 4, 8],
 8: [2, 3, 5, 6, 7]}
```

when i move from 1 to 7 my program pops 8 and then the search goes haphazard. I'm popping the last element. How can I implement this in python

Comment: Show us what you already have !

Comment: Yup. agreed with hivert. So that we can have a better idea of what your problems are.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want (depth first, left to right):

```
def dfs (node, graph, path = None):
    path = path if path else []
    if node in path: return path
    path.append (node)
    for child in graph [node]:
        path = dfs (child, graph, path)
    return path
```

Running it with your data it returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4]
```

Comment: cannot go to vertex 7 from 6 since 6 is not connected to 7.

Comment: @user3293224 You go from 8 to 7. At this point you are already backtracking.